# Emacs key input cheat sheet

Tags: function, emacs, dictionary, key

When you have the keycombination `C-x`, I would like to have some events occur at this key combinations, while awaiting following input.

For instance, I would like to, when I press `C-x`, to open up a new buffer with some text, and when followed by a new command, let's say `C-f` it then just follows that command.

Like this it would be possible to open up a cheat sheet for following commands everytime the first key is pressed, and then exited when the ending command has been chosen.

(suggestion for tags for this post are welcome, since I do not know appropriate ones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into [Icicles](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Key_Completion) it offers completion for key combinations so after you type C-x you can get a list of possible completions for that prefix.

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever tried to type C-h after C-x?

Comment: This could certainly be used. Now how to stick that C-h immediately after C-x, and then allow a command to be used?

Comment: The reason is that I'm writing a new mode and it would be good to have a visual reminder everytime I press a key.