# ajax-like command helper for EMACS?

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I am new to Emacs. I find it is powerful and very convenient IF one can master its set of commands. I also believe anyone can do this with patience, and the eagerness to learn and USE the software. However it will be much nicer for beginners, and seasonal users to have some command helper plugin that do following thing:

---

When the user start typing any CONTROL or META, COMMAND, or any special keys, a "ajax-like" or "smart search" window appear below or in the minibuffer showing help text like, for example: If I hold "CONTROL", command helper windows shows:

```
C-p         Up one line
C-n         Down one line
C-f         Forward one character
C-b         Backward one character
C-a         Beginning of line       
C-e         End of line
C-x         ...
```

Then if I continue to type "x" while holding "CONTROL", the window will update and show something like:

```
C-x C-a  add-mode-abbrev
C-x C-b  list-buffers
C-x C-c  save-buffers-kill-emacs
C-x C-d  list-directory
C-x C-e  eval-last-sexp
C-x C-f  find-file
C-x C-h  inverse-add-mode-abbrev
C-x TAB  indent-rigidly
C-x C-l  downcase-region
C-x C-n  set-goal-column
C-x C-o  delete-blank-lines
```

---

I have tried googling it, but it doesn't seem exist yet. So I guess this is more a feature request for EMACS rather then a question. But it is great if somebody can write a plugin/module to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come back to this be cause I found a perfect solution and can't live without it: The [`emacs-helm`](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) and [`which-key`](https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key)

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe this is out there, but I also believe that it is not really needed. It would just clutter the screen, though, maybe for a rookie it might be indeed useful.

For now, you might consider printing a [cheatsheet](http://cs.iupui.edu/~kweimer/EmacsCheatSheet.pdf).

Do not lose hope, I learned it without any sort of help, the key is indeed to just use it often.

Also, there is quite a good logic behind it all, so if you read up the structure in a cheatsheet or anywhere else, then it might help you "guess" what is the right key combo sooner than later.

**EDIT**: I actually myself asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988127/emacs-key-input-cheat-sheet), at least the same functionality was required. I accepted an answer which apparently mentions that [Icicles](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Key_Completion) offers this functionality.

Also, one advise is that after you type the prefix key, e.g. <kbd>C-c</kbd>, typing <kbd>C-h</kbd> afterwards will show you the possible completions.

This leads me to the following:

I believe we could use code like:
"If last key is a prefix key, run <kbd>C-h</kbd>*, switch back to previous buffer and rehit the last prefix key"

*this is a general method, working even for my own poorly designed minor mode

Comment: Maybe not for basic commands, but when using a package like `rinari` that defines many commands riding on the same prefix? I think it would a good alternative to using the menu. It would have to be maximally unobtrusive, though, so it doesn't get in the way when you do remember the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't know an existing package that would do that, but here's a couple of tips.

To get an overview of all available bindings, press <kbd>C-h b</kbd>. The displayed buffer looks fairly raw, because it includes all ways used to enter special characters (and they are usually at the top), but you can search it with <kbd>C-s</kbd> if you remember at least a part of the command name.

If you know the prefix (e.g. <kbd>C-x</kbd>) but don't remember what comes next, you can follow it with <kbd>C-h</kbd> instead (type <kbd>C-x C-h</kbd>). That will bring up a similar buffer that only contains bindings that start with the same prefix. It's one of the more obscure features, I think.

Speaking of "if I hold Ctrl", though, showing hints when you've just pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and nothing else if currently impossible to implement at the Lisp level. That would require some lower-level changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many keybindings in emacs for this to be practically useful.

I agree with the other responses and just wanted to add that I found the built-in tutorial very useful for getting past the basics.  You can reach the tutorial with <kbd>C-h t</kbd>.

You'll probably end up changing several of the default bindings, but learning them will help you find your way around new modes (assuming that they work in an "emacsy" way).